# How to sign jar using jarsign without providing -storepass?

Tags: java, jar, sign, jar-signing, jarsigner

Using jarsign without -storepass will prompt for the keystore password, which will break our automated build (no human intervention)

If we use jarsign with -storepass, then this will effectively log the password in cleartext in the build log.

Is there another way to pass storepass without using the command-line?

Comment: You could always pipe the input from a separate file. Though this is only slightly more secure because now you have a file stored on the system with passwords in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a script to call jarsign.

So in the build log, we only see the wrapper script.

Storepass is piped to jarsign so it's not visible on the command-line (as @Perception suggested).

Answer (score 0):

If you use Maven you could try with the [Jarsigner Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jarsigner-plugin/index.html). There you could load the storepass from a property defined in your settings.xml